# Rails not processing incoming requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-post

I'm working on a rails app and I'm running into an issue. Calling some of the routes in my app results in no response from the server. I checked the logs, and all they have is

`Started GET "/api/v1/cards" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-19 19:25:48 -0700`

Normally this is followed by `Processing by Api::V1::CardsController#index as JSON` but theres nothing like that for this call. It's the same way for all the routes in this controller. They all show up when I run `rake routes` however. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please post the controller code.

Comment: Your database could be dead. Your server could be out of disk space. You need to do some basic diagnostics here to see how pervasive this problem is.

Comment: Provide more details, Like your `controller` code or `logs`